# can Hudson Build do multiple builds with different web.configs

Tags: build, web-config, hudson

I use hudson build to build my application. I have a web.debug.config, a web.release.config and a web.beta.config. My question is this. Is there a way to make hudson build job to do a separate build for each of these every time I do a build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a serious lack of documentation on the Matrix projects and after trying all sorts I gave up on that and have a much simpler solution to what I was trying to achieve.

To achieve a build of each config I just added extra build steps with different command line parameters like this.

Click add a build step -> Build a VS project or solution with MSBUILD

In the command line arguments field add the following:
/property:Configuration=Debug

I then simply added another build step that does another build except with:
/property:Configuration=Release

And another with /property:Configuration=Beta

This runs through each build sequentially using the different configs on each build.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [matrix (multi-configuration)](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+matrix+project) project to do this, making the matrix variable the configuration type.

The linked documentation isn't too great, but hopefully it will get you going.

Comment: Yes I have read a bit about that but have not found any examples on how to set up the matrix project to build with the different config files. If anyone has seen an example a link would be appreciated.